# How can I pass values from one function to another?

Tags: c

I have created a program that takes in input "n" numbers that the user chooses and then prints the most repeated one, but I have a problem with passing the values between the functions so it gives me 0 as a result. How can I solve it?

```
void most_present_number(int array[]);
int read_numbers(int array[]);

int main() {
    int array[400];
    most_present_number(array);
    return 0;
}

void most_present_number(int array[]){
    read_numbers(array);
    int i = 0;
    int Max = 0;
    int Current_number = vettore[0];
    int Current_number_counter = 0;
    int most_present_number = 0;
    int most_present_number_counter = 0;
    while (i < Max) {
        if (array[i] == Current_number) {
            Current_number_counter++;
            i++;
        } else {
            if (Current_number_counter > most_present_number_counter){
                most_present_number = Current_number;
                most_present_number_counter = Current_number_counter;
            }
            Current_number = array[i];
            Current_number_counter = 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("The most present number is %d which is repeated %d times\n", most_present_number, 
           most_present_number_counter);
}

int read_numbers(int array[]){
    int Max = 0;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Insert the array lenght\n");
    scanf("%d", &Max);
    while (i < Max) {
        printf("Insert the numbers\n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return Max;
}
```

Comment: At least you need to write int Max = read_numbers(array); instead of read_numbers(array);
    int Max = 0;

Comment: What problem are you having? It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to include a complete set of code, sample input and output, and any error messages. Tell us what you expect to happen as well as what's actually happening. This will help us answer your question better.

Comment: As written, most_present_number() is iterating over at most 0 array elements. In other words, the condition of  while (I<Max) is never valid.

Answer (score 1):

You have `Max = 0` in `most_present_number()`, so the `while` loop stops immediately.

`read_numbers()` returns `Max`, so you can use this to initialize `Max` in `most_present_number()`.

```
void most_present_number(int array[], int Max);
int read_numbers(int array[]);

int main() {
    int array[400];
    int size;
    most_present_number(array);
    return 0;
}

void most_present_number(int array[]){
    int Max = read_numbers(array);
    int i;
    int Current_number = array[0];
    int Current_number_counter = 0;
    int most_present_number = 0;
    int most_present_number_counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Max; i++) {
        if (array[i] == Current_number) {
            Current_number_counter++;
        } else {
            if (Current_number_counter > most_present_number_counter){
                most_present_number = Current_number;
                most_present_number_counter = Current_number_counter;
            }
            Current_number = array[i];
            Current_number_counter = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("The most present number is %d which is repeated %d times\n", most_present_number, 
           most_present_number_counter);
}

int read_numbers(int array[]){
    int Max = 0;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Insert the array lenght\n");
    scanf("%d", &Max);
    while (i < Max) {
        printf("Insert the numbers\n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return Max;
}
```

Note also that your algorithm assumes that all the equal numbers will be together in the array. If they can be mixed up, you need a very different design. You need another array where you keep the counts of each number. Then at the end you find the entry in this array with the highest count.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the program does not start because in the global function `void most_present_number (int array [], int Max)` the variable `int Max` is not declared in the` void most_present_number (int array []) `function which comes after the main one